# exception floating parameter is not finite canvas

Tags: javascript, html, exception, image-processing, canvas

I wrote this code but I have a problem in line 18

```
    var c=document.getElementById("viewport");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var imgData= new Image();
    imgData.src = "q.jpg";
    var length = imgData.length;
    var width = imgData.width;
    var img=ctx.createImageData(length,width);
    imgData.onload = function(){
        for (var i=0;i<length;i+=4)
            {
               .
               .
               .
                }
                imgData.data[i+3]=255;  //alpha
            }
        ctx.putImageData(img,10,10);
    };
    console.log(img .toString());
```

at This particular line

```
var img=ctx.createImageData(length,width);
```

this is the exception that i get : **floating parameter is not finite** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your length & width vars are have invalid values when used in createImageData() because the image has not been fully loaded. That causes createImageData() to fail.

Instead:

```
// declare length,width & img
var length,width,img;


imgData.onload = function(){

    // set the values when the image has been fully loaded
    length = imgData.length;
    width = imgData.width;
    img=ctx.createImageData(length,width);
```